# Number rows 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3...ect

Tags: sql, presto

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS levels, 
       name 
FROM players_table
```

The above gives me the following

[image]

However, I'm looking to do this (start counting 1-3 every 3 rows) while still preserving the order.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can take the modulus

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER() % 3) + 1 AS levels, 
       name 
FROM players_table
```

Comment: Thanks, but any ideas how to preserve the order? The order is not intact when I use this - i.e. the first row is 2, second is 3, then it starts on 1, 2, 3 again

Comment: @coursepredict1 unless there is a column, like an id or timestamp, that defines the order of the rows, you can't preserve any order.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from  (select (row_number() over() %4) levels,
           name
         from
           players_table)t
where levels > 0
```

Comment: This will filter out 1 out of 4 rows of the table. Why %4?

Comment: This is actually in the order of n - 1 i.e 4 -1 = 3. This is done such that the required output is presented exactly as it is expected. Also if you observe, the where statement restricted the level count to start above 0.

Comment: This returns the sequence 0, 1, 2, 3 and filters out the rows numbered with 0. So, it is wrong.

Comment: oh, I see. Let me look more into it. thanks